# how assembly model type is actuall linked?

Tags: session, assembly, model, types

actually i want to make a long code but i have some trouble on some subroutines that are at the end of my code like the space i have is not enough, so i found something like breaking my code in sessions like .data .stack .model small etc. so breaking my code in sessions like these will give me a solution? how linker translate these sessions so that can work on long codes?
what kind of model types exist?
i am working with 8088, so if you know any 16 bit editor,compiler,debugger that i can use in windows i'd appreciate. thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have asked a lot of questions, but I suppose that the main question is how memory models work when it comes to compiling&linking of assembly code. Actually, I've no experience with 8088 processor, but I guess it's not very different than 8086, as it has to work in [real mode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#Real_Mode). 
OK, when you're writing an assembly code you've to choose memory model that your program is going to be in. It's done In your assembly by `.model` directive (AFAIR both TASM and MASM used it). 
This directive can have following parameters: TINY, SMALL, MEDIUM, COMACT, LARGE and HUGE. Each of them defines memory model of your program. TINY memory model means that your code and your data are going to be one segment. Other models allow you to declare code & data in separate segments. Or even declare a few segments that contain code (in case they exceed 64KB limit). That'd be for a starter.

Now, having all that said, we need to be note that different memory models change the way we're addressing data. If you chose TINY memory model your code and data are in the same segment. But in SMALL model they are not. So all your ASM instructions that access DATA segment are to have proper segment register set (DS).

Comment: ok let's assume that i have 300-350 lines of code. 50-60% of it is on subroutines but the 3-4 at the end of the code doesn't work (my programm stucks when it goes in there) i also could use some  standard variables in .data. what kind of model shall i use?

also how far/near affect procedures like that.

i know these are a lot of questions but if u could refer a tutorial/book/link also apreciated
 thanx